# How to save files(publically) on internal storage even if the external storage is available in android?

Tags: android, file, storage

How to save files(publically) on internal storage even if the external storage is available in android?

I want to save files on the internal storage root path even if the external storage is mounted.

Comment: One cannot put files in internal storage which you want to be public.

Comment: External storage is always mounted.

Comment: And then there is removable storage like micro SD cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose have a text file and save to local storage

```
public boolean saveFile(Context context, String myTextString){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(getFilename(),Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        out.write(myTextString);
        out.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt");
```

}

Hope this helps..

Comment: I want to save the file at /storage/emulated/0 not app's directory